# How to skip JSON levels when creating data classes

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'd like a nested JSON into flat data classes:

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    key_0: str
    key_2: str
    key_3: str
    key_4_1: str
    key_5: str

@dataclass
class MyDataClassList:
    classes: List[MyDataClass]
    
data = [
    {
        "key_0": "val_0",
        "key_1_to_skip": {
            "level_to_skip_1": [
                {
                    "level_to_skip_1_1": {
                        "level_to_skip_1_1_1": {
                            "key_2": "value_2",
                            "key_3": "value_3",
                            "key_4": {
                                "key_4_1": "value_4_1",
                                "key_to_ignore_4_2": "value_4_2"
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    "key_5": "value_5"
                }
            ]
        },
    }
]
```

Printing the instantiated `MyDataClassList` should return:

```
MyDataClassList(classes=[MyDataClass(key_0='value_0', key_1='value_1', key_2='value_2', key_3_1='value_3_1', key_4='value_4')])
```

How can I achieve this without creating all intermediate levels and mapping the whole JSON structure to a dataclass hierarchy?

Comment: Take a look at https://pypi.org/project/jq/, which lets you manipulate Python data structures using [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) filters.

Comment: This isn't something a dataclass (or any existing module that I am aware of) will do for you; you'll have to code the logic yourself.

Comment: There are two `"key_1"` keys in this. I suspect that this is too much of an edge case

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu it's not really an edge case. It's the structure of Shopify API data, with lot's of intermediary levels between the relevant data

Comment: I think what they meant is it's too much of an edge case to create a general-purpose library or API that would be able to understand that you want it to find specific keys at arbitrary depths. For example, `"key_0"`would need to be used multiple times whereas other keys are only used once. How would the API know which ones to use more than once without special casing it or the user specifying it.